# spark sql filter on map value fail when key is missing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table `tbl` with one MapType column `ref: map<string,string>`. I hope to filer by the value in this 'ref' column with key 'a'. This key is optional in every record. When it shows, the value of this key will always be '1'. Then when I try to do in this way: `select * from tbl where ref['a'] != '1'` I will not get what I want. But if I change code to this one: `select * from tbl where ref['a'] is null` everything is right. I checked the the physical plan, the filter pushdown only go to the level of column `ref`, so the value retrieve by key should not be affected when I use `ref['a'] != '1'`.
Why this happen?

my spark version is 3.2.1